# Pasar código de matlab a python con error en ciclo FOR

Tags: python, matlab

Tengo estos codigos en matlab el cual necesito pasarlos a python:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que me ayudaran a pasarlos a lenguaje de python ya que me quedo así y al correrlo me apareció un error en la linea del FOR por eso necesito ayuda para corregirlo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Información del sistema
wn=20 #[rad/s]
m=0.1 #[kg]
Fo=1 #[N]
xo= 0.001
x_punto=0.2
zeta=0.02

k=m*(wn**2)

omega=10 #[rad/s]
beta=omega/wn
 
wd=wn*((1-zeta**2)**0.5)

cc=2*(m*k)**0.5
c=zeta*cc

phi=np.arctan(c*omega/(k-(m*omega**2)))

t=np.arange(0,5,0.001)

d1=1-beta**2
d2=(2*zeta*beta)**2

Ap=((Fo/k)/(((d1)**2)+d2)**0.5)

xp= Ap*np.cos((omega*t)-phi)
a1=xo-(Ap*np.cos(-phi))
a2=(x_punto-Ap*omega*np.sin(phi)+zeta*wn*a1)/wd

xt = np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*(a1*np.cos(wd*t))+ (a2*np.sin(wd*t)) + xp

A=np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*((zeta/((1-zeta**2)**0.5))*np.sin(wd*t)+np.cos(wd*t))
B=np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*(np.sin(wd*t)/wd)
c1=(((1-2*zeta**2)/(wd*t)-(zeta/(1-zeta**2)**0.5))*np.sin(wd*t)-((1+2*zeta)/(wn*t))*np.cos(wd*t))
C=(1/k)*((2*zeta/(wn*t))+np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*(c1))
D=(1/k)*(1-(2*zeta/(wn*t))+np.exp(-zeta*wn*t)*((2*zeta*2-1/(wd*t))*np.sin(wd*t)+(2*zeta/(wn*t))*np.cos(wd*t)))

F=Fo*np.cos(omega*t)
u = np.zeros(len(t)-1)
u[0]=xo

for  i in range(len(t)):
    u[i+1]=A*xo[i]+B*x_punto[i]+C*F[i]+D*F[i+1]

#u=A*xo+B*x_punto+Fo*C+D

#Propiedades de los ejes
plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=7)
plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=7)

##Propiedades de figura fi, axl
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
fig.tight_layout()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.set_xlabel('Tiempo [t]', fontsize=8, loc='center')
ax.set_ylabel('Posición [x]', fontsize=8, loc='center')
ax.plot(t,xt, '--k', lw=1.4) 
ax.plot(t,u, '--k', lw=1.4)

plt.show()
```

Pero no me sale ya que considero que el problema está en el FOR de python y nose como arreglarlo, cuando estaba haciendo algunas correciones me apareció un error de flotante pero que a su vez está relacionado con el for.

Comment: cual es el error exacto? sino es muy dificil saber cual es el problema... yo veo algunas cosas que podrían fallar. 1_ definis u como una tupla (xo) en vez de como un array y las tuplas son inmutables (no las podés cammbiar). 2_ en python no podés agregar valores a un array indexando los valores nuevos (u[i+1] va a tirar error). 
Para solucionar estas dos cosas te aconsejo que definas de antemano u: `u = np.zeros(len(t)+1)
u[0]=xo`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, el error es justo en la línea debajo del FOR, este es el error que aparece: 'float' object is not subscriptable. Nose como hacer que funcionen las iteraciones para esa ecuación con el for.

Comment: Okey, fijate en lo que te digo, el error es porque el programa entiende que tu u es un flotante, no un array, definilo como sugerí antes y volvé a probar, andá agregando las modificaciones en ediciones, por más que no funcione, así tenemos de donde partir en la siguiente iteración

Comment: Dale, ya lo agregue pero sigue sin funcionar. Que más puedo poner para qué funcione?

Comment: Depende de los errores y cómo vaya quedando el código, por eso te decía que vayas modificando

Comment: estás intentando acceder a `xo[i]` y a `x_punto[i]` y ambos son escalares, no un vector, fijate por qué eso